# CKEditor embedsemantic do not get full media

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using the CKEditor Semantic Media plugins, but when I paste any media URL (e.g. from Twitter), after publishing `<oem>` disappears, displaying only the URL.

Twitter with `<oem>`:
[image: Twitter with <code><oem></code>]

Only link:
[image: Only link]

My config is :

```
config.extraPlugins = 'autoembed,embedsemantic';
config.autoEmbed_widget = 'customEmbed';
config.autoEmbed_widget = 'embedSemantic';
config.embed_provider = '//iframe.ly/api/oembed?url={url}&callback={callback}&api_key=MYAPI';
config.embed_provider = '//ckeditor.iframe.ly/api/oembed?url={url}&callback={callback}'
```

It does not work even on CKEditor demo:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> It does not work even on CKEditor demo:

It works for me. What browser are you using?